# MySQL Slow Order BY on Index Column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a table (book_list) that has about 4 million records. It has a PK (book_list_id) and when I run a query like below I get the results back in .060s

```
 select * from book_list bl ORDER BY bl.book_list_id LIMIT 25
```

Now when I run the virtually same query but sorting by book_title which is varchar(1200) and is indexed, it takes 34.7 s

```
 select * from book_list bl ORDER BY bl.book_title LIMIT 25
```

Is there something I can do to make this second statement faster?

BTW I also tried sorting by other numeric indexed fields and they too are very slow. Only the PK sorting seems to produce fast results.

Here is the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `book_list` (

`book_list_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`book_title` varchar(1200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`book_list_id`),

 KEY `indx_book_title` (`book_title`(255))

 ) 
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4733798 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please, post show create table.

Comment: what does runing 'explain ...' show you?

Comment: Do you have 4millions of indexed books? ;)

Comment: Dmitry: When I run EXPLAIN sorting with book_title the EXPLAIN "Extra" reads "Using filesort" but when I run EXPLAIN for book_list_id "Extra" reads blank

Comment: danihp: Please see CREATE TABLE which I added above

Comment: danihp: I just created a simple PK for book_id and then a single index for book_title..nothing fancy

Comment: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips

Comment: Klaus: That site lists a lot of potential causes. Any idea which of the causes would account for a simple PK sort being 30x faster than an indexed sort?

Comment: Book title is varchar 1200 not varchar 200. Null is allowed, do you have a lot of nulls?

Comment: Sorry, title is 1200 chars. There are no NULLs; though I did add a new numeric column with a simple Index and added some values, with some nulls, to see if that would be faster but it too was much slower than the PK sort.

Comment: Perhaps the reason is just that individual index entries are 4 bytes for the integer column and 766 bytes for the varchar column. That's a larger amount of data to compare.

Comment: Hammerite is right. If title length is 1200 and index length is 255, RDBMS should reorder rows for the 1200-255 remaining characters, may be this? 34,7s are a lot of time, where is bottleneck in this middle time? Disk? CPU? Can this help in this issue? If you get pk for 25 first rows by title and make a query asking for this hard coded pks, is fast?

Comment: ahhhh..can I just resize my index? Would there be a reason not to do something like that?

Comment: you can also do 'order by left(book_title, 255)', which shouldn't have any trouble using the index.  Though, you may still get titles that are over 255 chars showing up out of order.  But at least you can test the theory without making any changes to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad performace is due to the fact that not all field is indexed, only firsts 255 characters. RDBS must compare 1200-255 characters to make the final order.

Increase the portion of field that is indexed or make the query to sort only by firsts 255 characters as  @Dmitry Beransky say:  'order by left(book_title, 255)'

Answer (score -2):

Could you please try:

```
select * from book_list where book_list_id in
(select book_list_id from book_list order by book_title limit 25);
```

Comment: That gives the following error: [Err] 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'